# Is there a reason the hot wire is connected to the neutral bar and the white to the breaker?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

The black wire is connected to the neutral bar and the white wire is connected to the breaker. Should it be this way for any reason?

Comment: Not any **normal** reason. Can you post a picture of the panel?

Comment: That's pretty weird, no, there's no legitimate reason to ever do that.  Maybe they had a black wire go bad on them and they used white for hot and bootlegged ground for neutral...

Comment: @Harper doesn't sound like bootlegged ground - sounds like a simple *reversal* of black & white. Which is dangerous.

Comment: Yes, can you post a picture of the inside of the panel? Also, can you find the first outlet on the circuit, and post a picture of the inside of its box?

Comment: I purchased a house that was wired that way In Ohio, not just 1 but all the hots and neutrals reversed.

Comment: Voting to close. Not enough detail and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 1):

No. I suggest you test the outlets on the circuit with an outlet tester. I use the 
[Gardner Bender GFI-3501](https://www.gardnerbender.com/en/p/GFI-3501/Ground-Fault-Receptacle-Tester).